# How can i add background color to part of constrainlayout in Android studio?

Tags: xml, android-layout, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout

i have created a simple constrain layout with a list of button on the right most column.  I have set the entire background as transparent , but some how want to cover column just behind the buttons to have other color background. what are different option i can have to achieve this design. Any help would be highly appreciated
I have added two screenshot as well. First screen shot is with entire constraint background transparent as a output from my xml code . I wish to have another background marked by blackbox behind buttons another color. how can i acheive it .

my xml code with image button using constrain layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:background="#00000000"

    android:gravity="center">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonShowPreview"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="120dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="showPreview"

        android:src="@drawable/decline"
        android:textSize="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textViewPeer"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/surfaceIncomingVideo"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.716"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.547" />




    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonAccept"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="44dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="acceptCall"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"

        android:src="@drawable/answer"
        android:text="Accept"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.946"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textViewCallState"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.794" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/voiceCall"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:visibility="invisible"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/surfaceIncomingVideo"

        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.419"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/surfaceIncomingVideo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.466"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/voice" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:background="@null"

        android:onClick="hidevideo"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/videohide"
        android:text="Accept"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mute"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.944"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/buttonHangup"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="hangupCall"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/decline"

        android:text="Reject"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonAccept"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.956"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/mute"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"

        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="unmute"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/mute"

        android:visibility="invisible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonHangup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.946"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.777"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/unmute"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="mute"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/unmute"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/buttonHangup"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.942"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/surfaceIncomingVideo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageButton"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.395" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply put some view under your buttons (this view will be the part of the screen that you want paint with color) and give it a color:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#57DDAADA"
        app:layout_constraintWidth_percent="0.25"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button7"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button9" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button8"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/button10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button9"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/button5"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

[image]